# Scrolling a particular web element using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape company's jobs offer  from [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_C=1110%2C12800%2C5115950%2C3165553%2C603115%2C10916%2C8331%2C3297950%2C8238%2C5509188%2C3093%2C2625246%2C1112%2C947572%2C11018069%2C407323&geoId=92000000). I need to scroll a section in the page (with an inner scrollbar). I have been trying this :

1.

```
   scroll_active = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.application-outlet > div.authentication-outlet > div.job-search-ext > div > div > section.jobs-search__left-rail > div > div > ul")))
   scroll_active.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

2. 

```
while driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div'):
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
     Divs=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').text
     if 'End of Results' in Divs:
       print 'end'
       break
     else:
       continue
```

[Need to extract 'href'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6UDs.png)

Answer (score 0):

If any one facing that, I wish this could help, you just have to **choose well** the element that you  want to scroll

```
my_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/section[1]/div/div")))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', my_xpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do need to scroll here?
seems like you can get all of the element by command:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='result-card__full-card-link']")
```

and looks like:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_C=1110%2C12800%2C5115950%2C3165553%2C603115%2C10916%2C8331%2C3297950%2C8238%2C5509188%2C3093%2C2625246%2C1112%2C947572%2C11018069%2C407323&geoId=92000000')
time.sleep(3)

def element_present():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='infinite-scroller__show-more-button infinite-scroller__show-more-button--visible']")
    except Exception:
        return False
    return True


while not element_present():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='result-card__full-card-link']")
hrefs = [el.get_attribute('href') for el in elements]

print(hrefs)

print(len(hrefs))

driver.quit()
```

might I missed smth, but seems like it works well as well

Comment: thx for your answer, but it just gives me the first 7 items and the others are invisible. this is why I needed  the scroll. I tried also to wait until the visibility of all items but it didn't work. any way I found a solution I wrote it down , you have just to  select well the needed element and execute a JavaScript code. thx for your time

Comment: sorry but I don't know if linkedin is making new settings or what cause I don't have show more button it's just  pagination

Comment: the pb is that I need the login, I'm working on other data that  demand to be logged in in order to extract it .. sorry if I'm bothering you but could help me controlling the speed of scroll, i'm using this instruction to scroll : driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', my_xpath)

Comment: unfortunately , from what I understood your answer works in case you are not logged in . it's just weird cause whenever I make a request to LinkedIn it asks for login